# LINQ - Select from parent list where grand-child list matches condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have an `employeeCollection` that looks like this.

```
var `employeeCollection`= IQueryable<Employee>
                              |- IQueryable<Parent>
                                   |- IQueryable<Sibling>
                                        |- IQueryable<Child>
```

Meaning, `employeeCollection` has a child `IQueryable<Parent>`, which then has a `IQueryable<Sibling>` collection, which then has a `IQueryable<Child>` collection.

I want to filter the `employeeCollection` such that it does not contain a `Child` with a name that starts with "Q". Meaning if an `Employee` has a `Parent` that has a `Sibling` who has a `Child` named "Quinn", that employee should be filtered out.

How would I do that?

Comment: I assume you know `linq` then simply use a hefty amount of piped `.Any`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please update your post to include what you've tried and what isn't working. Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it seems you're looking for a `Where` statement with a negation of a bunch of nested `Any` methods, because you only need one nested instance to exclude it.

```
employeeCollection.Where(emp => 
    !emp.Parents.Any(par => 
        par.Siblings.Any(sib => 
            sib.Children.Any(cld => cld.name.StartsWith("Q"))
        )
    )
)
```